# SwiftUI No image named was found in main bundle

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm studying SwiftUI and have a problem with Image(name: String).

This is my ContentView

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("test")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 75, alignment: .center)
            .clipped()
        List(retriever.items) { item in
            Row(coin: item)
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this project, I got this message
"Thread 1: Fatal error: No image named test was found in main bundle"

So, I tried below.

- Image("test.jpg")
- Image("images/test")
- Image("images/test.jpg")

But, the result was same.

That image was in this path
'project root/images/test.jpg'

---

Strange thing is that this code works well.

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "test.jpg")!)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue. It works if I do the same as the alternative `Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "test.jpg")!)`. have you resolved this?!

Comment: I experienced a similar issue with the images not being found when I was working on a class-platform app. The problem occurred only on macOS app. The solution was to provide an image for each resolution: initially I provided graphics for @3x only but it seems that macOS doesn't see them :)

Comment: Hey! Do you have any news?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add your images to the Assets Catalog in your Xcode project structure so Apple can do some behind the scenes magic to prep them for use with multiple screen sizes. Double click your Assets.xcassets folder (make an assets folder if you don't have one) in your project pane on the left of your xcode editor, then drag and drop your image file into the catalog pane.

Calls like `Image("your_image_name")` should work after this.

Comment: I accepted this answer but haven't tried this solution

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had the assets catalog inside a swift package, I used this code

```
Image("header", bundle: .module)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your image to Assets.xcassets folder. Error message telling you literally  - 'I can't find this image at Assets.xcassets'.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem still occured, even though I cleaned build folder.

Comment: I encounter the same problem even using xcassets, what are we missing here?

Comment: Please upload you project to something like GitHub, and share link. @JulienSanchez

Comment: @Radagast I am seeing the same issue. Here is the github link ( https://github.com/badrinathvm/SwiftUI ), any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your imageset's `Contents.json` contains the same name of image name. Please see the below image.

[image: ImageSet of Conference Room]

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I think swift defaults to .png files. Perhaps when you simply write Image("test") it is looking for "test.png"

Try saving your image as a .png, placing it in the assests folder, and using Image("test") like you have been using above.

Comment: This is correct, it defaults to looking for files with ".png" extension. You don't even have to add files to the xcassets per se - if they are being shipped inside app bundle (as .png's), then they will be discoverable

Answer (score 1):

Also check that the Assets.xcassets is included to be copied in the Bundle Resources.  You can find this by going to Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

[image: Image showing the Build Phases menu, with expanded Copy Bundle Resources section]

Answer (score 1):

Came across this thread from Google. None of the answers worked for me. I had dropped that `PNG` file into the project and this worked:

```
if let image_url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "selfie", withExtension: "png") {
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: image_url.lastPathComponent)!)
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .resizable().scaledToFit()
}
```

I had to use the overloaded version of `Image(uiImage: UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName:))`. Just specify the file name of that image only, using absolute path of the image file won't work

Answer (score 0):

Save your image in PDF format ("test.pdf") and drag it into the asset catalog’s editor
=> Image("test") will be ok ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue based on Monica's answer. It endup that my Assets.xcassets was not included in the Bundle resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the bundle:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
Image("test", bundle: bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped. The image was part of the assets, in the correct directory, in the Json file etc. Once I restarted XCode the image showed up.

Answer (score -2):

You need to name your images xx@1.png and xx@2.png and xx@3.png,
Then create New image Set in the Assets directory of the xcode project, rename it, and drag the image of the corresponding size to it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oXgm.png)